# Equivalence of WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted and WebBrowser.Navigating event in WebView2 in winforms application

Tags: c#, winforms, webview, webview2

I updated the `WebBrowser` into `WebView` in winforms application to use `Edge` browser. But I am facing some problems while updating. Among them, `WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted` and `WebBrowser.Navigating`events are not found in the new `WebView2`. I tried `NavigationCompleted` and `NavigationStarting` these two events respectively instead of them. But I am facing these problems.

1. Scrolling on `Mouse Wheel` is not working. I need to drag the scroll bar to scroll.
2. `Window.location == 'app://language/'` (in JavaScript code) is not calling the `NavigationStarting` events.

How can I get rid of these two problems?

Comment: Have a look at [known issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/webview-known-issues) and [faq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/webview#frequently-asked-questions-faqs) sections

Comment: [WebView control for Windows Forms and WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/webview#frequently-asked-questions-faqs). See also the `DOMContentLoaded` event and the `Frame` loading related events.

Answer (score 2):

In WebView2 there are two events which help you detect load event:

- [`WebView2.NavigationCompleted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.winforms.webview2.navigationcompleted?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.705.50) → is raised when the WebView has completely loaded (body.onload has been raised) or loading stopped with error.
- [`WebView2.CoreWebView2.DOMContentLoaded`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32/icorewebview2_2?view=webview2-1.0.721-prerelease#add_domcontentloaded) → is raised when the initial html document has been parsed. This aligns with the the document's DOMContentLoaded event in html. (This one is available starting from 1.0.705.50.)